# How to pass function in object as a parameter

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to do PHP program using OOP but I am stuck with some problem.

PAGE 1: mainclass.php (contains all important functions)

```
<?php
class mainclass
{
    /* Database connection*/
    public function db_config()
    {
        $c=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if($c)
        {
            mysql_select_db("empdb",$c);
            mysql_close($c);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "CONNECTION ERROR";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: a) Suggestion: Find another php tutorial. One that uses mysqli or PDO instead of the old, deprecated mysql_* module and has more error handling. b) the mysql_close after mysql_select_db kinda makes that class useless. c) In what way is that code related to the "question" title? d) _Do_ you have a question?

Comment: which is the function that you want to pass as object?

Answer (score 1):

```
$my_func = function() {
    return 'hello';
};

$foo = new NewClass($my_func);

class NewClass {
    public function __construct($my_func) {
        echo $my_func();
    }
}
```

Comment: your code gives this-> `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$foo'`

Comment: I was missing a semi colon. It's fixed now.